# Scripts.RenderFormat async error

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, scripting

When i add an async attribute, my code throws an exception like this:

```
@Scripts.RenderFormat("script async type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{0}\"> script>", "~/bundles/jqueryvalidation")
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

the async keyword is causing the browser to download and begin executing the scripts in the jqueryvalidation bundle immediately...probably before the jquery library on which it depends has been downloaded, hence you get the Uncaught ReferenceError because jqueryvalidation depends on jquery which hasn't been loaded yet

you either need to remove async so that it only loads after jquery has loaded, or combine the 2 bundles into another bundle that you can then download asynchronously